# Missing the lzma lib?

Tags: python, pip, lzma

The following message means that Python has not been installed completely.
If Yes! Do I have to install the 'lzma' extension?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module name '_lzma' 
Warning: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib? 
Installed Python-3.11.3 to /Users/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3

Thank you!

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about programming, do probably belongs on a different Stack Exchange site. Nor does it even show what commands caused the error, or what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ArAsH, did you [install the build-time dependencies](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) before installing Python with pyenv? I suspect not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [Chris' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028283/missing-the-lzma-lib/76310848#comment134092700_76028283), the solution is to [install OS-specific dependencies](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) *then* use `pyenv` to install a python version.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac:

You need to install xz so that it finds the lzma module from the OS.

```
brew install readline xz
```

For ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

For centos:

```
yum install -y xz-devel
```