# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma' kivy app

Tags: android, github-actions, kivymd, buildozer, lzma

I made a kivymd app with instaloader module. But it Crashes during run time.In my spec file these are my requirements `requirements = kivy,kivymd,python3,hostpython3,pillow,certifi,instaloader,requests,android`
Here's my debug log

```
<module>
I/python  ( 7985):    File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stalkgram/arm64-v8a/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 24, in <module>
I/python  ( 7985):    File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stalkgram/arm64-v8a/instaloader/nodeiterator.py", line 7, in <module>
I/python  ( 7985):    File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
I/python  ( 7985):    File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
I/python  ( 7985):  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
I/python  ( 7985): Python for android ended.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.I've followed tons of methods but i failed

I've tried some methods from the internet but in my github actions root directory i didn’t find any .buildozer directory where the lzma.py exist.Everyone are telling me to modify the 27's line of lzma.py but no such file or directory.
Thanks

Comment: This is your issue: _but in my github actions root directory i didn’t find any .buildozer directory where the lzma.py exist_. These files should be in your docker image, not in github actions dir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing the lzma lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028283/missing-the-lzma-lib)

Comment: Then why the error throwing the path ```I/python  ( 7985):    File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
I/python  ( 7985):  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'```